# How to change the variable used in a keyword based on the browser in which I'm running the robot script?

Tags: robotframework

I have to change the value of the variable depending on the browser in which I'm running the script. I have my code as given below:

```
    *** Variables ***
    ${upload_file}          xpath=//*[@id="file"]
    ${path_jpg}            ${EXECDIR}\\test_data\\Browse_Image\\apple.jpg
    ${path_png}            ${EXECDIR}\\test_data\\Browse_Image\\apple.png
    ${path_gif}            ${EXECDIR}\\test_data\\Browse_Image\\apple.gif
    ${path_webm}           ${EXECDIR}\\test_data\\Browse_Image\\apple.ppt
    ${browse_remove_edge}  xpath=/html/body/app-root/div/div/div/project-creation/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a
    *** Keywords ***
    Upload a .jpg image
      load "${path_jpg}" into "${upload_file}"

    Upload a .png image
      load "${path_png}" into "${upload_file}"

    Upload project image (unsupported format)
      load "${path_webm}" into "${upload_file}"

    Upload a .gif image
      load "${path_gif}" into "${upload_file}"
```

In the above code, If my browser is edge, the script has to use variable ${browse_remove_edge} instead of ${upload_file}
And also i have declared my browser in a variable "${browser}" as follows:

```
    ${browser}  chrome
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) or [Set variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If)?

Comment: Perhaps the technique of using [variables in variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables-inside-variables) will work for you to be able to extend the support for browsers.